# Post facebook photo with link

Tags: ios, facebook

I have an iOS application which could export pictures to Facebook. At the moment I create App specific album during first posting and post "photos" (actually drawings) to this album.

There is one huge disadvantage of this method - there is no link to my facebook page at all. So this postings don't make any sense for promotion.

I have only one idea at the moment: create own hosting, upload picture there and post link to it, but that requires webapp with hosting == additional expenses.

Is there any other way to combine picture and link to my Facebook page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could consider using tumblr. It is free and has a pretty good API. host your images there and then create links for them and post to Facebook

http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. Are you suggesting to use Tumblr instead of Facebook?

Comment: Nope. Upload the images to tumblr and link to the tumblr image from facebook. We have an app in our Company that applies this strategy